# IsExpanded only works on first level of TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeviewitem, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm using a TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate but can't get the IsExpanded property working for higher levels than the first. Here's my xaml:

```
<TreeView>
     <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

In my ResourceDictionary I have:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```

what makes the first order work.

In higher indention levels IsExpanded is always false because the PropertyChangedEventHandler is not fired for children.

Here's my class:

```
public class ListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (isExpanded != value)
            {
                isExpanded = value;
                SendPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
        }
    }
    private void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Children { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT: I'm very sorry, my corrected code is working!**

Comment: Are you chaning the value at runtime? If so you should implement [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), also it should be `public`. *(By the way, the plural of `child` is `children`)*

Comment: I'm new to WPF and not sure how that works. I have to inherit my items from the INotifyPropertyChanged class but how to get the PropertyChanged handler called for higher levels than the first?

Comment: It's not a class, it's an interface, you might want to have a look at the general [data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and the [article detailing the implementation of INPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx). This has nothing to do with tree levels.

Comment: Follow this. It is fired every time the property is set:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: yes sorry, it's an interface... but the event is not fired for the children

Comment: If you still have "bool IsExpanded { get; set; }" you should remove it as it may be overriding your correct INPC property. Besides that I think it should work

Comment: I removed "bool IsExpanded { get; set; }" but the problem is still the same: SendPropertyChanged is not called for the children

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically expand all the children as well the target item then you need to propogate the change downwards yourself, do something like this....

```
public bool IsExpanded 
{ 
    get { return isExpanded; } 

    set 
    { 
        if (isExpanded != value) 
        { 
            isExpanded = value; 
            if (isExpanded)
            {
                foreach(ListItem child in Children)
                    child.IsExpanded = true;
            }
            SendPropertyChanged("IsExpanded"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want to save the whole tree state